# Issue with installing packages with pip: "Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH"

Tags: python, rust, pip

I am using a Python virtual environment to work on a project. After setting up my venv and pulling from git I tried to `pip install -r requirements.txt` but am getting the following error:

```
Collecting orjson==3.5.2
  Using cached orjson-3.5.2.tar.gz (740 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am using Python version 3.10.2, pip version 22.0.4.

Any idea how to fix this? I installed rust but it did not fix it.

I am not getting the errors below after moving my virtual enviroment to local.

```
Collecting orjson==3.5.2
  Using cached orjson-3.5.2.tar.gz (740 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      ðŸ’¥ maturin failed
        Caused by: Cargo metadata failed. Does your crate compile with `cargo build`?
        Caused by: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

      Caused by:
        process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Z mutable-noalias=yes --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit code: 1)
        --- stderr
        error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler
      Error running maturin: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', 'C:\\Users\\jawan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-modern-metadata-hjcwzhua', '--interpreter', 'C:\\Users\\jawan\\Desktop\\Programming\\imotor\\Scripts\\python.exe', '--manylinux=off', '--strip=on']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      Running `maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory C:\Users\jawan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hjcwzhua --interpreter C:\Users\jawan\Desktop\Programming\imotor\Scripts\python.exe --manylinux=off --strip=on`
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Can you run `cargo --version` in your console. What is the result?

Comment: @BigG 1.59.0 on the PC but not found in my virtual environment.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @pitaJ Windows 10, 64bit

Comment: Is your python environment 64-bit or 32-bit? In this Github issue that is similar to your issue, it seems the problem was having a 32-bit python envirnment. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2811

Comment: It is 64 bit. I am now getting new errors after moving to local environment. I added them to my question above.

Comment: A virtualenv shouldn't mess up your PATH such that another executable can't be found. There's something else going on, but without knowing how you installed rustup/cargo/rust, and without knowing how you set up and activated your v-env, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Per the new error message: "Does your crate compile with `cargo build`". Though the non-ASCII characters in the preceeding line are slightly worrying.

Comment: Oh: probably the answer to your second attempt is in the error message: "error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler". I'm not sure what package you are trying to install, but it sure is picky about its dependencies.

Comment: Please do take the time to read through an error message and troubleshoot it as necessary.

Comment: I downgraded python to version 3.9.10 and was able to resolve the errors above.

Comment: Nice. Then I guess it is probably because there are binary wheels for 3.9, but not yet for 3.10 (for which it then needs to build from scratch, as indicated near the top of the messages).

Comment: Note that there *are*, in fact, wheels for Python 3.10, but those are for `orjson` 3.6.7. So the `orjson` version you want to install does not have a binary version readily available for Python 3.10.

Comment: I am able to install it using Git Bash as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248498/9475509.

Answer (score 8):

Try installing the tooling for the Rust programming language, because it seems like you have a dependency that uses Rust.

For mac OS, I recommend using [brew](https://brew.sh/).

```bash
brew install rust
```

Otherwise use the steps from the [Rust install page](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

You can check that rust is installed properly with:

```bash
rustc --version
```

Once you are finished try again to pip install your requirements file.

Comment: had that issue and installing rust fixed it

Comment: this worked perfectly on mac

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading my pip distribution in the newly created environment first solved the issue for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the docker image python:3.12-alpine. This answer was the first one I found. When I tried to install the rust compiler on the alpine container, my pip package (solana dependency - solders) took forever to compile. The only solution I found was to use python:3.12-bookworm instead. It didn’t require any compilation or rust installation. It just worked out of the box. I hope my answer helps someone save a few evenings.

Comment: I had the same problem with `python3.12`, switching to `python3.11` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, and after installing the 64-bit version of Python everything is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Simply install the dependency:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: This is the only thing on this page that worked for me; however, you left out an important detail. It didn't work until I closed my terminal session and opened a new one.

Answer (score -1):

I already had a 64-bit version of Python (as mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73594451/2745495)) but I was still facing the same problem. I upgraded pip and then everything worked fine. I did not have to install Rust.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022 console to execute the command 'pip install open interpreter'

Answer (score -3):

The above error is caused by a rust package

```
pywinpty
```

all you need do is to remove it from requirements.txt file
and redeploy your app.