# Error to install Jupyter Notebook for Python in Windows 10 using PIP

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i am very on amateur on these things. I downloaded pip and then i used this `python get-pip.py` to install pip which completed successfully and then i used `pip install jupyter notebook` and i got the below error

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Any help will ve appreciated

```
  Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2130]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\antonis>cd Desktop

C:\Users\antonis\Desktop>python get-pip.py
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-22.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, pip
  WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.3
    Uninstalling pip-22.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.3
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.10.exe, pip3.11.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\antonis\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-22.3 wheel-0.37.1

C:\Users\antonis\Desktop>pip install jupyter notebook
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
Collecting notebook
  Using cached notebook-6.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (439 kB)
Collecting qtconsole
  Using cached qtconsole-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
Collecting jupyter-console
  Using cached jupyter_console-6.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting nbconvert
  Using cached nbconvert-7.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (271 kB)
Collecting ipykernel
  Using cached ipykernel-6.16.1-py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting ipywidgets
  Using cached ipywidgets-8.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (134 kB)
Collecting jinja2
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting tornado>=6.1
  Using cached tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (425 kB)
Collecting pyzmq>=17
  Using cached pyzmq-24.0.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (990 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi
  Using cached argon2_cffi-21.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting traitlets>=4.2.1
  Using cached traitlets-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core>=4.6.1
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client>=5.3.4
  Using cached jupyter_client-7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
Collecting ipython-genutils
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting nbformat
  Using cached nbformat-5.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting nest-asyncio>=1.5
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.5.6-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Collecting Send2Trash>=1.8.0
  Using cached Send2Trash-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.3
  Using cached terminado-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting prometheus-client
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Collecting nbclassic==0.4.5
  Using cached nbclassic-0.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 MB)
Collecting jupyter-server>=1.8
  Using cached jupyter_server-1.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (346 kB)
Collecting notebook-shim>=0.1.0
  Using cached notebook_shim-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting entrypoints
  Using cached entrypoints-0.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\antonis\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->notebook) (2.8.2)
Collecting pywin32>=1.0
  Using cached pywin32-304-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (12.1 MB)
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Collecting bleach
  Using cached bleach-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting defusedxml
  Using cached defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting markupsafe>=2.0
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1.tar.gz (18 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting mistune<3,>=2.0.3
  Using cached mistune-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting nbclient>=0.5.0
  Using cached nbclient-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (71 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\antonis\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (21.3)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.4.1
  Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting tinycss2
  Using cached tinycss2-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting fastjsonschema
  Using cached fastjsonschema-2.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=2.6
  Using cached jsonschema-4.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting pywinpty>=1.1.0
  Using cached pywinpty-2.0.8.tar.gz (23 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696582/issue-with-pip-install-in-virtual-environment-cargo-the-rust-package-manager

Comment: thanks @possum just if you can help a bit more. In the link you shared with me it says "The above error is caused by a rust package" it gives this code "pywinpty" and then it says "all you need do is to remove it from requirements.txt file and redeploy your app". What i need to remove? and how i will do it ? when it says to redeploy the app means to uninstall Python and install it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is usually related to your python version, you can try to delete python 3.10 and install 3.9

Comment: I tried Python 3.12 and still have the problem.

Comment: I am able to install it using Git Bash as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248498/9475509.