# Error while Installing Jupyter Notebook using pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to install Jupyter Notebook without Anaconda. I am using Python Version 3.12.0.

While installing Jupyter Notebook using `pip install notebook`, following error occured.

```
Collecting pywinpty (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook)
  Using cached pywinpty-2.0.11.tar.gz (26 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.*
```

- Upgrade `pip` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67764065/9475509) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123636/9475509) does not work.
- I do not want to downgrade Python [from 3.10 to 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173787/9475509) or [from 3.12 to 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77246694/9475509).

Can anyone help me solving this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I uninstalled Python 3.12 and downgraded to 3.11 and it worked. I was able to install Jupiter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not install it using Windows Command Prompt, but I am able to install it using Git Bash.

Following are the version information

- Windows 10.2.22621
- Git 2.42.0.windows.2
- Python 3.12.0 (64 bit)
- pip 23.2.1

And the installed Python packages are

```
D:\python>pip list
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
anyio                     4.0.0
argon2-cffi               23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0
arrow                     1.3.0
asttokens                 2.4.0
async-lru                 2.0.4
attrs                     23.1.0
Babel                     2.13.0
backcall                  0.2.0
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2
bleach                    6.1.0
certifi                   2023.7.22
cffi                      1.16.0
charset-normalizer        3.3.0
colorama                  0.4.6
comm                      0.1.4
contourpy                 1.1.1
cycler                    0.12.0
debugpy                   1.8.0
decorator                 5.1.1
defusedxml                0.7.1
executing                 2.0.0
fastjsonschema            2.18.1
fonttools                 4.43.0
fqdn                      1.5.1
idna                      3.4
ipykernel                 6.25.2
ipython                   8.16.1
isoduration               20.11.0
jedi                      0.19.1
Jinja2                    3.1.2
json5                     0.9.14
jsonpointer               2.4
jsonschema                4.19.1
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1
jupyter_client            8.3.1
jupyter_core              5.3.2
jupyter-events            0.7.0
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0
jupyter_server            2.7.3
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4
jupyterlab                4.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2
jupyterlab_server         2.25.0
kiwisolver                1.4.5
MarkupSafe                2.1.3
matplotlib                3.8.0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6
mistune                   3.0.2
mpmath                    1.3.0
nbclient                  0.8.0
nbconvert                 7.9.2
nbformat                  5.9.2
nest-asyncio              1.5.8
notebook                  7.0.4
notebook_shim             0.2.3
numpy                     1.26.0
overrides                 7.4.0
packaging                 23.2
pandocfilters             1.5.0
parso                     0.8.3
pickleshare               0.7.5
Pillow                    10.0.1
pip                       23.2.1
platformdirs              3.11.0
prometheus-client         0.17.1
prompt-toolkit            3.0.39
psutil                    5.9.5
pure-eval                 0.2.2
pycparser                 2.21
Pygments                  2.16.1
pyparsing                 3.1.1
python-dateutil           2.8.2
python-json-logger        2.0.7
pywin32                   306
pywinpty                  2.0.12
PyYAML                    6.0.1
pyzmq                     25.1.1
referencing               0.30.2
requests                  2.31.0
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1
rpds-py                   0.10.4
scipy                     1.11.3
Send2Trash                1.8.2
six                       1.16.0
sniffio                   1.3.0
soupsieve                 2.5
stack-data                0.6.3
sympy                     1.12
terminado                 0.17.1
tinycss2                  1.2.1
tornado                   6.3.3
traitlets                 5.11.2
types-python-dateutil     2.8.19.14
uri-template              1.3.0
urllib3                   2.0.6
wcwidth                   0.2.8
webcolors                 1.13
webencodings              0.5.1
websocket-client          1.6.3
```

I hope it helps, even I do not understand why it works.