# Why can't I install keybert using pip install?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to use keybert following the instructions [here](https://maartengr.github.io/KeyBERT/guides/quickstart.html), as I want to use it to identify keywords from text. However, when I try to install it via the terminal on my IDE (VS Code), I get the following error:

```
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
```

Forgive my ignorance, but I have no idea what this means. At first I thought it may have something to do with the version of Python that I am using (3.12), but I am not so sure. When I downloaded Python 3.8, for example, and used that as the interpreter, I seemingly got the same error...

Comment: Either keybert or one of keybert's dependencies requires rust, so the error is hinting it needs Rust tooling to proceed with the installation. Check the answers in [Issue with installing packages with pip: "Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71696582/2745495)

Comment: *Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/* answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
```

As it shows, the package you installed depends on Rust. You have to install it manually from https://rustup.rs/